# Where to find Caliburn.Micro 1.4 documentation?

Tags: mvvm, windows-8, documentation, windows-runtime, caliburn.micro

I want to start using Caliburn.Micro (I've been using MVVMLight in the past), and I saw that there is a new version compatible with WinRT (1.4). I downloaded it and wanted to get started, but all the examples on the internet are old and don't work any longer. I couldn't find any official documentation for version 1.4. The official documentation is outdated as well.

For example: I used this guide: http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/caliburn-micro-winrt-getting-started.aspx, but when I'm setting up my Bootstrapper, I cant do this:

```
container = new WinRTContainer(RootFrame);
```

Because I get an error that `WinRTContainer` doesn't accept any parameters.

I also need this method:

```
protected override Type GetDefaultView()
{
    return typeof(MainPage);
}
```

But `GetDefaultView()` isn't an overridable method.

So can anyone please point me to some up-to-date documentation or a nice getting started guide? I'm looking specifically for a Windows 8/WinRT version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will be updating the documentation soon. I apologize for that. If you download the release from codeplex, there is a HelloWinRT sample in the samples directory. That should show you how to get started and use several common features such as navigation and search.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Could you please provide what is new in version 1.4? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Mainly, we've fixed a bunch of bugs and added support for Win8 and Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably start with launching the samples for WinRT provided with the package and reading Readme.txt file.